# cordova read android library images

Tags: cordova

I've been using the same code on SDK29 and has previously worked, i've now updated to target SDK30 and I'm getting an ERR_ACCESS_DENIED message when selection an image from the phones image library. Both set in Config.xml

```
<config-file target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest" overwrite="true">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<button onClick='receiptPhotos.getPhoto(this, pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);'>Photo Library</button>


navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI) {receiptPhotos.onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI, $element);}, receiptPhotos.onFail, { quality: $quality, targetWidth:$targetWidth, targetHeight:$targetHeight, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: $source , encodingType:Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,mediaType:Camera.MediaType.PICTURE, correctOrientation: true});


onPhotoURISuccess: function (imageURI,$element) {   
...
img.src=imageURI;
...
}


ERR_ACCESS_DENIED: 
file:///data/user/0/com.App.Demo/cache/Screenshot_20220224-102846_image.jpg?1647872951452
```

Is there another config.xml permission I need to add?

Comment: I've just come across an article which mentions android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION - jsut trying it now

Comment: android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a plugin not identified within the log

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because the permissions have changed for files in SDK30+
You can add to your config.xml

```
  <preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```